# What is my error in this seemingly simple integration? $ \int \frac {-x}{x+1} dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, substitution

This is what I've got: 
$$  \int \frac {-x}{x+1} dx  =-1 \int \frac {x}{x+1} dx $$ Then I create the following substitutions: $ u=x+1 $ , $ du=dx $, $ x=u-1 $, which gives me: $$ -1 \int \frac {u-1}{u} du $$ I proceed: $ -1 [\int \frac {u}{u} du - \int \frac{1}{u} du] $ = $-1 [u- ln|u|]+C $ = $ -1[x+1-ln|x+1|]+C $

Then Finally: $$ -x-1+ln|x+1|+C $$

My TI89 says the correct answer is $$ ln|x+1|-x $$ . What happened to my -1?

Comment: It was absorbed into the constant $C$.

Comment: One can also avoid substitution, by the way, by writing the integrand as $-\left(1 - \frac{1}{x + 1}\right)$.

Comment: @Travis still you have to substitute $u = x+1$.

Comment: Thank you! So as a general rule, any constants resulting from indefinite integration become irrelevant because of the + C, correct?

Comment: $\int f(x)dx$ is ANY anti-derivative of $f(x),$ not THE anti-derivative. Any two anti=derivatives of $f(x)$  will differ from each other by  a constant. BTW it is easier to use $\int (-x/(x+1))dx=\int (-1+1/(x+1))dx=-x+\ln |x+1|.$

Comment: That is correct

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**:$$\large-1+C={ C }_{\text{new constant}}$$

Comment: Thank you! So as a general rule, any constants resulting from indefinite integration become irrelevant because of the + C, correct?

Comment: you are welcome.Yes